# Broke my company's network, how do I get it set back up?

Tags: dhcp, local-area-network, windows

My dad moved his office. The new location will only have WiFi access, but he still needs his server setup and the other machines connected to it.

The server (don't laugh) is an old Windows NT 4.0. Then I'm trying to connect just a standard Dell desktop to it (running Windows XP).

The old location had a broadband network. When I'm on the server, I can't connect to the DHCP. Since there's no internet access (and a server to connect to via Broadband connection), how do I set the ip address for the server. IP config says no ip address for the server (obviously). I've googled a bunch for "configure windows nt lan/dhcp/network" and I'm not getting the right information (or it's there and I don't realize it).

Is there a link someone could post for a tutorial? All we need to do is share files and printers...

Comment: Windows NT 4.0? For _real_?! We aren't laughing, we're crying. Don't even _attempt_ to do anything with that ancient monstrosity other than remove your data from it and power it off forever.

Comment: unfortunately, that's not an option. We're dealing with the cheapest people on earth here...

Comment: Sorry, they've cheaped out for about 15 years longer than they should have with that thing. It is about your _only_ option.

Comment: seriously, a downvote?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. But I can tell you that a _professional_ would charge more than the cost of a new server to even _look_ at NT 4.0 at this point.

Comment: The downvote was mine, misunderstood the question and thought you were talking about a home setting "...my parents network", which is quite offtopic here. It's gone again.

Comment: Windows NT 4.0 leaves you vulnerable to viruses, malware and remote attacks. Connecting Windows NT 4.0 directly to the internet (without a good network firewall) is a very bad idea, and even with a firewall you are still vulnerable to many web-based attacks. Systems like that are hacked regularly and used as nodes in botnets and are the source of Spam attacks, nodes used in DDoS attacks, etc.

Comment: This Windows NT4 server does not have to be on the internet. There are no viruses to be had on his local network if he's running a local network only. Not everything needs to be connected to the internet.

Comment: Correct @cpattersonv1, this will not be connected to the internet. They already have a router (non-Wifi), and I'm using that to connect the machines, printers, and server.

Comment: You cheap out, and it bites you in the ass.  Welcome to the biting.  Hope you've had a rabies jab.

Comment: @ganders What is the router you talk about for if not for connecting to the internet? Sounds like a switch would be enough ... (Wait a minute? Why was this question even bumped to "hot"? It's actually an April fools thing, isn't it?)

Answer (score 7):

This started off as a comment - but it's getting a bit long.

Your biggest problem is not the version of software you run but the availability of skills to manage, plan and support the service. By the sound of things this is really basic stuff - but if you approach anyone who makes their money from selling stuff, then they are going to say you have to buy stuff (you probably will need to buy stuff - but upgrading the OSs / hardware should be the LAST thing on your shopping list).

Currently there is an oustanding task that will take someone competent 3-5 minutes to fix. Go see if you can bribe one of the guys walking out of your nearest PC store at closing time to see if they'll do it for you. That will get you up and running. However your dad needs some better guidance with how to sort this out - sounds like a couple of hours of *competent* consultancy work - not sales!

`We're dealing with the cheapest people on earth here` - it sounds like they are now in a position to start considering the **value** of basic IT management.

Comment: This is what I said in short. His old network was already on a broadband router with a DHCP server (hence the lack of knowledge of DHCP.) Installing a router they already had or buying a new cheap router would fix the issue.

Comment: Server, printer, and workstations are all connected through the router. I just can't get anything to recognize each other...